# Hopf algebra and coideal question

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, hopf-algebras, coalgebras

Let $A$ be a Hopf algebra (over a field). Consider a unital subalgebra $B\subseteq A$ with $\Delta(B)\subseteq B\otimes A$. Put
$$B^+:= B\cap \ker(\epsilon).$$
It can be shown that $B^+$ is a two-sided coideal of $A$, so that $AB^+$ is also a two-sided coideal.

**Question**: If $x\in AB^+$, is it true that $S(x) \in B^+ A?$

Of course, it suffices to show that $S(B^+)\subseteq B^+ A$ but I am not sure how to show this.

Thanks in advance for your help/comments/suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed true, and it forms part of the proof of a result known as ***Koppinen's Lemma***.

The argument is as follows: Let $\{x_j\,|\, j \in J\}$ be a basis  of $B^+$, and take an element $x \in B^+$. It follows from the counit axiom of a Hopf algebra, and linear independence of our basis, that we can write the coproduct of $x$ as
$$
\Delta(x) = x \otimes 1 + \sum_{j} x_j \otimes y_j, \textrm{  for some } y_j \in A^+. 
$$
Applying $\epsilon \circ \eta = m \circ (S \otimes \mathrm{id})$ to this expression, we get the identity
$$
S(x) = - x_jS(y_j) \in B^+A.
$$

As I wrote above, this is a step in Koppinen's Lemma, which states, under the assumption of a bijective antipode, that
$$
S(AB^+) = B^+A. 
$$
An elementary proof (from which I took the above argument) along with a reference to the original article of Koppinin, can be found in this [article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02810683). (An open access copy can also be found on Schneider's LMU Munich website.)

It is also interesting to note that if $B^+A = AB^+$, then Koppinen's Lemma implies that the Hopf algebra structure of $A$ descends to the quotient $A/B^+A$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Completely clear!